# How to activate hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation

My overleaf will not hyphenate my doc no matter what i do.
I've put this into my preamble:

```latex
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
```

What's wrong?

---

Here is the first picture of my preamble
[image: PREAMBLE 1]

Comment: Hyphenation is the standard approach: we will need to see an example _complete_ document to help.

Comment: I've converted to an edit, but pictures really are not what is needed. We need edited-in code that provides a complete document (starting `\documentclass` and ending `\end{document}`, but with only enough content to show the issue.)

Comment: I tried to, but there are too many characters to put in the whole preamble

Comment: We are unlikely to need all of your preamble: you will need to create what is called a 'minimal working example'. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that for advice on creating one.

Comment: Ive made a new post:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667745/how-to-activate-hyphenation

Comment: I'll close here but ideally don't open multiple questions, edit the one you've started