# How to activate hyphenation?

Tags: hyphenation

My overleaf will not hyphenate my doc no matter what i do. I've put this into my preamble:

```
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
```

What could be wrong?

Preamble:

```latex
\documentclass[english,a4paper,11pt,fleqn,oneside,opgenany,oldfontcommands]{memoir}     % Openright aabner kapitler paa hoejresider (openany = vilkaarlig/begge)



\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tabularx}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
\usepackage[english]{babel}             
\usepackage{ragged2e,anyfontsize}           
            
\usepackage{rotating}                   


\usepackage{nomencl}


\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}               
\usepackage{graphicx}                       
\usepackage{multirow}                   
\usepackage{colortbl}                       
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}         
\usepackage{flafter}                        
\usepackage{float}                          
\begin{figure}[H]
\usepackage{placeins}
\let\newfloat\relax                                             
\usepackage{lscape}                 
\begin{sideways}...\end{sideways}
\usepackage{gensymb}


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       
\usepackage{mathtools}                      
\usepackage{textcomp}                       
\textperthousand)
\usepackage{siunitx}                        
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}       
\usepackage[english]{varioref}              
\usepackage[super]{natbib}                  
\externaldocument{<NAVN>}




\usepackage{listings}                       
\begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}
\usepackage{lipsum}                         
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}          
\usepackage{pdfpages}                           
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=6                 
\pretolerance=2500                          


\usepackage[footnote,draft,english,silent,nomargin]{fixme}      



\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}  
\setlrmarginsandblock{Indbinding}{Kant}{Ratio}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}      
\setulmarginsandblock{Top}{Bund}{Ratio}
\checkandfixthelayout                   
\usepackage[footnote,draft,english,silent,nomargin]{fixme}
%   ¤¤ Afsnitsformatering ¤¤ %
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}                 
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}                   
\linespread{1,1}                            

% ¤¤ Litteraturlisten ¤¤ %
\bibpunct[,]{[}{]}{;}{a}{,}{,}              
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}               


% ¤¤ Dybde af overskrifter ¤¤ %
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}             
\settocdepth{subsection}                    

% ¤¤ Lister ¤¤ %
\setlist{
  topsep=0pt,                               
  itemsep=-1ex,                             
} 


\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}           
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true,              
    linkcolor = black,
    citecolor = black,
    urlcolor = black
}


\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}      
\captionnamefont{\small\bfseries\itshape}   
\captiontitlefont{\small}
\usepackage{hhline} %bruges til at lave dobbeltlinjer horisontalt i tabeller
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont={small,bf, it}]{caption}


\captiondelim{. }   
\hangcaption                             
\captionstyle{\centering}                   
%\captionwidth{\linewidth}                  
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}          
        

\definecolor{commentGreen}{RGB}{34,139,24}
\definecolor{stringPurple}{RGB}{208,76,239}

\lstset{language=Matlab,                    
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,        
    keywords={for,if,while,else,elseif,     
              end,break,return,case,
              switch,function},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},              
    commentstyle=\color{commentGreen},      
    stringstyle=\color{stringPurple},       
    showstringspaces=false,                 
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,        
    extendedchars=true,                     
    columns=flexible,                       
    breaklines, breakatwhitespace=true,     
}


% ¤¤ Navngivning ¤¤ %
%\addto\captionsdanish{
    %\renewcommand\contentsname{Indholdsfortegnelse}            
    %\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendiks}                  
    %\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendiks}
    %\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendiks}
    %\renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername~}                
    %\renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}          
%}


\definecolor{numbercolor}{gray}{0.7}    
\newif\ifchapternonum

\makechapterstyle{jenor}{                   
  \renewcommand\beforechapskip{0pt}
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\chapternonumtrue}
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{db}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{0.9in}{0in}\selectfont\color{numbercolor}}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \noindent
    \ifchapternonum
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
    {\let\\\newline\chaptitlefont ##1\par} 
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip-2.5mm\hrule
    \else
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
    {\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont ##1}} & \raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip2mm\hrule
    \fi
  }
}                                           

\chapterstyle{jenor}                    

\usepackage{lastpage}       
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Aalborg University}
\lhead{\leftmark}                               
\rfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}    
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}            



\figur{Stoerrelse}{Fil}{Figurtekst}{Label}
\newcommand{\figur}[4]{
        \begin{figure}[H] \centering
            \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{billeder/#2}
            \caption{#3}
            \label{#4}
        \end{figure} 
}


\newcommand{\dec}{^{\circ}}                                 % '\dec' returnerer et gradtegn (husk 
\newcommand{\decC}{^{\circ}\text{C}}                        % '\decC' returnerer et gradtegn + 'C' 
\newcommand{\m}{\cdot}                                      % '\m' returnerer et gangetegn



\hyphenation{In-te-res-se e-le-ment}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You really should go through your preamble and delete the things you don't need. Better yet, start from scratch and only add those things that you really need and of which you know their function.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty good example of how a preamble should ***not*** be written.

It mixes package loading and settings in an inextricable way; there are duplicate calls and dubious settings: for instance, `memoir` has its own method for setting headers and footers, making `fancyhdr` not the best choice for the job.

You do even worse with

```
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
```

because a document should stick with just one dialect of English. Moreover, `british` is the same as `UKenglish`, whereas `USenglish`, `english` and `american` are exactly the same.

But this is not related to missing hyphenation: well hidden in the confusing preamble you will find

```
\pretolerance=2500
```

which looks like an innocent declaration, but actually it says to TeX that preposterously bad paragraphs are good and hyphenation should not be tried when the overall badness is 2500 or less. Hyphenation will be tried only when the badness exceeds 2500.

The fact is that, when trying to typeset a paragraph, TeX does a first pass without trying hyphenation. If the badness doesn't exceed `\pretolerance`, the paragraph is typeset. Otherwise a second pass is performed with hyphenation and the relevant parameter is `\tolerance`. A third pass might then be attempted if `\emergencystretch` has a positive value and the badness exceeds `\tolerance`. The standard values are

```
\pretolerance=100
\tolerance=200
```

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=400pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\kant[2]

\newpage

\pretolerance=2500

\kant[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

At no stage the badness of lines in the second paragraph exceeds 2500, so the paragraph can be typeset without hyphenation. But there's a line with badness 1231, the one starting with “faculties”. And one line more.

Here's an amended version of the preamble; look at the comments marked with `<---`.

```
\documentclass[
  english,
  a4paper,
  11pt,
  fleqn,
  oneside,
  openany, % <--- not opgenany
  %oldfontcommands, % <--- DON'T!!!
]{memoir}     % Openright aabner kapitler paa hoejresider (openany = vilkaarlig/begge)

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <--- no longer necessary
\usepackage[english]{babel}             

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}                       
\usepackage{rotating}                   
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{multirow}                   
%\usepackage{colortbl} % <--- pass table to xcolor
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{flafter}
%\usepackage{float} % <--- DON'T use [H] under any circumstance
%\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{gensymb} % <--- dubious usefulness
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{textcomp} % <--- no longer necessary
\usepackage{siunitx}                        
\usepackage[super]{natbib}                  
\usepackage{listings}                       
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}          
\usepackage{pdfpages}                           
\usepackage[footnote,draft,english,silent,nomargin]{fixme}      
%\usepackage{anyfontsize} % <--- obsolete
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}      
\usepackage{hhline} %bruges til at lave dobbeltlinjer horisontalt i tabeller
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont={small,bf, it}]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lastpage}       
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % <--- it would be better to use memoir features

\usepackage[english]{varioref}              
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}           

%% settings

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5} % <--- Really?

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}       

\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}  
\setlrmarginsandblock{Indbinding}{Kant}{Ratio}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}      
\setulmarginsandblock{Top}{Bund}{Ratio}
\checkandfixthelayout                   
%   ¤¤ Afsnitsformatering ¤¤ %

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}                 
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}                   
\linespread{1.1} % <--- NOT 1,1

% ¤¤ Litteraturlisten ¤¤ %
\bibpunct[,]{[}{]}{;}{a}{,}{,}              
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % <--- unsrt is not compatible with natbib               


% ¤¤ Dybde af overskrifter ¤¤ %
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}             
\settocdepth{subsection}                    

% ¤¤ Lister ¤¤ %
\setlist{
  topsep=0pt,                               
  itemsep=-1ex,                             
} 


\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor = black,
    citecolor = black,
    urlcolor = black
}

% <--- the following should be done with caption features
%\captionnamefont{\small\bfseries\itshape}
%\captiontitlefont{\small}
%\captiondelim{. }   
%\hangcaption                             
%\captionstyle{\centering}
%\captionwidth{\linewidth}
%\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}

\definecolor{commentGreen}{RGB}{34,139,24}
\definecolor{stringPurple}{RGB}{208,76,239}
\definecolor{numbercolor}{gray}{0.7}

\lstset{language=Matlab,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
    keywords={for,if,while,else,elseif,
              end,break,return,case,
              switch,function},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{commentGreen},
    stringstyle=\color{stringPurple},
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    extendedchars=true,
    columns=flexible,
    breaklines,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
}


\newif\ifchapternonum

\makechapterstyle{jenor}{                   
  \renewcommand\beforechapskip{0pt}
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\chapternonumtrue}
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{db}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{0.9in}{0in}\selectfont\color{numbercolor}}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \noindent
    \ifchapternonum
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
    {\let\\\newline\chaptitlefont ##1\par} 
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip-2.5mm\hrule
    \else
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
    {\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont ##1}} & \raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip2mm\hrule
    \fi
  }
}                                           

\chapterstyle{jenor}                    

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Aalborg University}
\lhead{\leftmark}                               
\rfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}    
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}            

\newcommand{\dec}{^{\circ}}                                 % '\dec' returnerer et gradtegn (husk 
\newcommand{\decC}{^{\circ}\text{C}}                        % '\decC' returnerer et gradtegn + 'C' 
\newcommand{\m}{\cdot}                                      % '\m' returnerer et gangetegn



%\hyphenation{In-te-res-se e-le-ment} % <--- wrong hyphenations for English
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted

```
\pretolerance=2500
```

And now it works.

Comment: Unfriend whomever advised you to.. but that’s not the only part to remove from your preambile.

Comment: Its a Danish template for beginners and ive only been using latex for 1 month so i can't determine what to delete or keep. Im afraid if i delete something and the document no longer will convert to pdf

Comment: Honestly, for a beginner that template is overdone. Suggestion: Get a book on Latex introduction of about 100 pages, or skim through this one: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX . After that, start simple documents using the article class. Look up and skim through the descriptions of the many packages from that template, like https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx . Sucess and understanding will come quickly. As Leslie Lamport put it, Latex is about logical design, less about visual design. Its defauls already result in nice typesetting.